# Wi-Fi significantly slower on Ubuntu 20.04.1 than on Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, windows, atheros

I noticed when downloading some files that my Wi-Fi speed is very slow on Ubuntu compared to Windows 10. Here are my results:

What I'm paying for: Download: 150 Mb/s, Upload: 10Mb/s

Ubuntu 20.04.1: Download: 6 Mb/s, Upload: 10 Mb/s

Windows 10: Download: 80 Mb/s, Upload: 10 Mb/s

I used speedtest.net and I used the same server for both of the tests. I also used Google Chrome and did not move my laptop between the tests. I tried everything in [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/), but none of the solutions helped.

Here's the output of `sudo lshw -C network` in case it helps:

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 31
       serial: <removed>
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:135 memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

If you need any more information I'll try to answer as soon as I can.

Comment: If it's true that Ubuntu20 has slower internet than Win10, the solution to this problem can be gold.